# Как считать данные из таблицы Excel в DataFrame в специальном формате? Библиотека Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Допустим есть следующая таблица

```
    Time  Value1  Value2
0    10     30.5    21.6
1    11      11     50.2
2    13      13     13.33
3    15     101.1    2
4    23       5      5
5    4      11.1     10
```

Мне нужно считать ее в DataFrame но не полностью, а предварительно отфильтровав. К примеру, сложить каждые две строки в одну, т. е.

```
    Time  Value1  Value2
0    21     41.5    71.8
1    28     114.1   15.33
2    27     16.1     15
```

Сначала считать весь файл, а после изменять в нем - **НЕАКТУАЛЬНО**. Спасибо.

Comment: `Сначала считать весь файл, а после изменять в нем - НЕАКТУАЛЬНО` - почему??

Comment: Считать и изменить будет проще и быстрее. В противном случае вам колхозить на гораздо более низком уровне решение придётся.

Comment: Хорошо, если я считал, то каким образом провести следующие действия?

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите, например, [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/) и итерируйтесь по строчкам, на каждой итерации выполняя необходимые действия и сохраняя куда либо результат. Потом результат можете превратить в DataFrame

```
for row in ws.iter_rows('A1:C2'):
    ...
```